# .awaitMessageComponent() in an ephemeral reply and then editing it

Tags: discord.js

I have been trying to implement an interaction collector as per the discord.js guide, but the guide does not explain much of anything and the pieces I have puzzled together from other sources do not fit together. Here's the example from the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-message-component):

```js
message.awaitMessageComponent({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 60000 })
    .then(interaction => interaction.editReply(`You selected ${interaction.values.join(', ')}!`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`No interactions were collected.`));
```

It took me a day to figure out that you can define a message object like so:

`message = await interaction.channel.send(content: 'text', components: >select menu<)`

That works to run `.awaitMessageComponent()` and to grab the input from the select menu, however `interaction.editReply()` gives an error: `INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED`

Moreover, I need it to be a reply anyway, however
`message = await interaction.reply(content: 'text', components: >select menu<)`
leaves `message` as undefined, so of course I cannot run `.awaitMessageComponent()` on it.

So I do not understand what I am supposed to do to do what that guide is doing.
I would very much appreciate any insight into this issue.

Unfortunately all other guides (usually on collectors) also start with a `.send()` message and most other resources go way over my head, as I have no real background in coding/scripting.

EDIT:

As Malik Lahlou points out, you can assign the reply by including the `fetchReply:`option, like so:

```js
message = await interaction.reply({ components: [select menu], fetchReply: true })
```

However that still does not allow the guide's code to run (error `INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED`, so after some more research I finally found a way to use `.awaitMessageComponent()` and applied to the guide's example it would look like this:

```js
await interaction.reply({ components: [select menu], ephemeral: true });

const collectedSelect = await interaction.awaitMessageComponent({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 60000 })
    .then(interaction => interaction.editReply(`You selected ${interaction.values.join(', ')}!`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`No interactions were collected.`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, add the `fetchReply` option when replying to the interaction :

```js
const message = await interaction.reply({
//  content : ...,
//  components : ...,
  fetchReply: true
})
```

Another way would be to use interaction.fetchReply after awaiting the reply but it's better to directly give it as a parameter so discord.js does this stuff for us :D Here's an example on the [official discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#execution-with-discord-js-code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I can now assign the message.
However, now I am also getting the error
`[INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.`
I am, starting to think I might have misunderstood what exactly this method is for?
My goal is to receive a slash command, then reply (ephemerally) with a select menu (this far no problems) and then I thought `.awaitMessageComponent` plus `.editReply` would let me edit the original reply (that has the select menu in it).

Comment: @Urinstein That's because you're listenning to the interaction's components, then .editReply (editing the reply)  which isn't really logical, instead use a `await interaction.reply({ components : [selectmenu] )` before.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm too thick-skulled to understand, what you mean. My command block is quite literally only `message = await interaction.reply([select_menu], fetchReply)` followed by the guide's code block I posted in my op and get the aforementioned error, after a selection is made. So I am not sure if you mean I need to add another `await interaction.reply({ components : [selectmenu] )` somewhere? Does it have to go somewhere else? And what about it is isn't logical?

Comment: Someone taught me, that GitHub has a search function. So I found this: https://github.com/nirewen/uno-bot/blob/53730df9a6a00286422a04668d36ce02ec10cf0a/src/commands/uno.ts
It works as I need and expected it to. Although this still leaves me at a loss over how to get the guide's code to run.